# How to design something like this in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How to design a golden spiral flower like this one?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This would have been created using Illustrator. To use Photoshop for this would have been a pain in the ass - and almost impossible without blurring. Check out this tutorial for a starting point - https://gomedia.us/zine/tutorials/transform-again-adobe-illustrator/